# Running a loop in the background in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Not certain what options I have, I want to run a loop within a controller that runs in the background and steps every n'th milli seconds, it will just change the colour on a button, want it to go from green to orange and then back using ng-style.

What is a sensible approaches to running a loop in the background, for obvious reasons I would like to avoid locking up the whole page just to have a button changing colour.

Comment: I would really want to thank for everyones input. In this particular case, I wanted to use angular if possible, as there is quite a few things that needs to happen on the angular front and the animations will eventually be dependent on code in angular. Besides I want to get better at that framework. Certain all the other solutions works as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using Angular, you should use the Angular solution: [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

A simple example, assuming you're using a boolean in the scope to determine whether the button is green or orange:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myController', ['$scope', '$interval',
        function($scope, $interval) {
            $scope.isGreen = true;

            $interval(function() {
                $scope.isGreen = !$scope.isGreen;
            }, 1000);
        }
    ]);
```

This will toggle `$scope.isGreen` every second.

Comment: Damn right! If using AngularJS `$interval` is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps a css option might be the way to go here. You can loop animation in css.

[Keyframe Animation Syntax](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/)

Here's an example

```css
@-webkit-keyframes looping-background {
  0%   { background-color: orange; }
  50% { background-color: green; }
  100% { background-color: orange; }
}
@-moz-keyframes looping {
  0%   { background-color: orange; }
  50% { background-color: green; }
  100% { background-color: orange; }
}
@-o-keyframes looping {
  0%   { background-color: orange; }
  50% { background-color: green; }
  100% { background-color: orange; }
}
@keyframes loopingN {
  0%   { background-color: orange; }
  50% { background-color: green; }
  100% { background-color: orange; }
}

.loop_animation {
  -webkit-animation: looping-background 2s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    looping-background 2s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      looping-background 2s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         looping-background 2s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}
```

```html
<button class="loop_animation">I am a button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a javascript event timer to call a function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers

Answer (score 1):

why dont u you use

```
setTimeout(function(){
                          // change the color of button here
                          }),n*1000);
```

this set time out should be called in recursive loop .

```
<body onload = "changeButtonColor()">

<script>
function(){
         // change the color here 
         setTimeout(function(){
                          // change the color of button here
                          }),n*1000);
         }
</script>
```